# IsSMTP() in phpmailer function

Tags: php, phpmailer

> ****Fatal error: Call to a member function IsSMTP() on a non-object****

I get this error in my program. I have tried `$mail=isSMTP(true);`
Please help me understand why this error occurs and how I can resolve this error

Answer (score -1):

You need to create an instance of an object before you call methods on it, and post your whole code when asking a question on SO.